# Can I have the DC_PEN use the PS_INSIDEFRAME style?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, gdi

I'm updating some old GDI code and I'd like to switch to using DC_PEN and SetDCPenColor() for a significant performance boost.

Unfortunately, the old code creates its pens with PS_INSIDEFRAME instead of PS_SOLID. PS_INSIDEFRAME creates a solid pen but the coordinates are also treated slightly differently when drawing rectangles.

Is there a way I can update DC_PEN to use this style for my DCs?

Comment: I don't know the answer unfortunately, but I'm curious if you've actually done any performance testing that shows DC_PEN is significantly (or at all) quicker?

Comment: Yes, my tests show that it's significantly faster. Using DC_BRUSH and DC_PEN removes a lot of SelectObject(old), DeleteObject(), CreatePen(...), SelectObject(newPen) cycles. We did cache a number of pens/brushes which helped but even with that, the benefit has been around 30% faster using the DC_PEN/BRUSH combo.

Comment: of course, YMMV and we may have other (in)efficiencies which contribute to the difference as other refactorings are also helping in my case.